# Under Archlinux. How do I keep track of debug info for packages ?

Tags: arch-linux, package-management, pacman, pkgbuild

I have the need for debug info for **glibc**.

I constantly copy **PKGBUILD** out of **/var/abs**, and build the package, every time after I upgraded **glibc**.

I wonder whether I can save the effort? Either forcing **pacman** do the job for me, or taking advantage of some other package managers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ABS is [being considered for deprecation](https://lists.archlinux.org/pipermail/arch-dev-public/2017-March/028752.html), so you should move to an alternative approach anyway.

The replacement for ABS is [asp](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=185075), a git based alternative for building from source.

For your required package, you just init the git repository (`asp export glibc`), and then whenever you need to update you can switch into the directory and run `asp update glibc`.

Because it is just a git repo, you can further simplify your workflow by creating your own branch with any patches etc., and then rebasing and running `makepkg -i` in that branch for your build and install.

asp is [developed by Dave Reisner](https://github.com/falconindy/asp), one of the Arch developers, so will likely make it into the supported repositories once ABS is officially abandoned.

Comment: But how can I be sure `asp update glibc` gives me the matching **PKGBUILD** version with source pulled from **glibc** git repo?

Comment: It will give you the source for the latest version in [core], which will point to the latest stable release from upstream.